# Existence of interacting scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-analysis

I saw a comment in Schwartz's introductory text on Quantum Field Theory (cf. Section 14.5) that it is known that $\phi^4$ theory in five dimensions *does not exist*. In four dimensions it is not known, while in lower dimensions it was proven to exist. Other field theories are unknown, one of which --- Yang-Mills theory --- is part of the Clay's Mathematics Prize.

For the scalar field this is a very surprising result: what is the obstruction in five dimensions? I cannot find the resources pointing this either, heuristically or rigorously.

I would also love to see if there is generic descriptions on what is the general obstructions that make generic proofs of this sort of results so hard. For QED, at least, I could imagine gauge invariance getting in the way (not that I know how), but what about real scalar field theory (massive or massless)?

Comment: In 5d the scalar $\phi$ has dimension $3/2$, so $\phi^4$ has dimension $6>5$, and thus $\phi^4$ is an irrelevant interaction in 5d. This implies that 5d $\phi^4$ theory is not a renormalizable field theory: you can treat it as an effective field theory, but it is not UV-complete.

Comment: You can only have $\phi^3$ interaction in 5d, which is slightly relevant, but it leads to potential which is unbounded from below.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk by your argument (which I guess involves renormalization group flow), it would mean that $\phi^4$ does not exist for $d\geq 5$, not just $d=5$?

Comment: $\phi^4$ does not exist in $d>4$. It is not really renormgroup. Suppose that the theory exists at least for small values of the coupling. Let's then try to do perturbation theory. If interaction is irrelevant, you will find that infinitely many diagrams will be divergent, and you will need infinitely many counter-terms to your action in order to cancel these divergences. The divergent part of these counter-terms is fixed by the requirement that the divergences cancel, but the finite part is ambiguous. (You cannot just say that finite part is 0 because there is no canonical way to separate it..

Comment: .. from the divergent part.) So you need to specify infinitely many renormalization conditions (read: coupling constants) in order to make sense of perturbation theory. So this is the problem. If you wish you can interpret it in RG language: you start with free theory, which is a fixed point, and try to perturb it by some interaction. If you add relevant interaction, you are changing the IR and you theory is UV-complete by construction -- it is simply the free theory in the UV. But if you are adding an irrelevant deformation, you are trying to change the UV so that the IR fixed point is the ..

Comment: .. free theory you started with. There are infinitely many ways of doing so. For example, you could have a lattice theory which flows in the IR into free scalar at long distances, and you can tweak the lattice a bit in infinitely many ways without affecting the IR fixed point. These infinitely many choices are reflected in the infinitely many counterterms that you get in perturbation theory: depending on which UV-completion you choose, you'll get different values for finite parts of the counter-terms.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk I think the comments are too extensive. Why not type it as a potential answer? I think it's more coherent.